# Create dynamic variable names in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I have a problem with dynamic variable names

I have form paramters like

```
ip1
ip2
ip3
dns1
dns2
...
```

I know how many, but I don't know how to create the variable names in the controller

```
def ipcount = params.count
    for (i = 1; i = ipcount ; i++ ){
         def systems = new Ip() 
         systems.inetAddress = params.ip+${i}  <---- How do I create these variable name?
                 ....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just enclose them in double quotes:

```
def ipcount = params.int( 'count' )
def systemsList = (1..ipcount).collect { i ->
    def systems = new Ip() 
    systems.inetAddress = params."ip${i}"
    ...
    systems
}
```